# jQuery hide/show element depend on html select value

Tags: jquery

I am sure its something trivial, even so i have a problem with hiding/showing element via jQuery depand on selected value on html form. I have this html:

## HTML

```
<select name="town" id="town" onchange="otherTown()">
    <option value="1">New York</option>
    <option value="2">Washington</option>
    <option value="3">London</option>
    <option value="4">Other</option>
</select>

<div id="alt_town" style="display:none;">
    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Other Town</label>
    <input type="text" id="right-label" name="alt_town">
</div>
```

## JS

```
function otherTown() {
    $('#town').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "4") {
            $("#alt_town").show()
        } else {
            $("#alt_town").hide()
        }
    });
}
```

When user choose "Other" option in select, "Other Town" form show up. It works but only after i choose something else before "Other" option (for example "London" option). I need to element shows even if "Other" is first choice.

Thank you guys for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your inline event handler, you are registering the jQuery change handler(which is toggling the display) only in the inline event handler, so when the first change is happening there is no jQuery handler to execute so nothing happens.

When the second change is triggered, you have the handler registered in the previous event that gets invoked and the display is changed, but it will cause multiple change event handlers to be invoked since each change will add a new jQuery event handler

There is no need for the inline handler

```js
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#town').on('change', function() {
    //use toggle for ease of use
    $("#alt_town").toggle(this.value == 4)
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="town" id="town">
  <option value="1">New York</option>
  <option value="2">Washington</option>
  <option value="3">London</option>
  <option value="4">Other</option>
</select>

<div id="alt_town" style="display:none;">
  <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Other Town</label>
  <input type="text" id="right-label" name="alt_town">
</div>
```

Comment: `toggle()` with a boolean is always preferable to `hide()`/`show()` pairs. As per @A. Wolff.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yes... missed that.. and was updating it

Answer (score 1):

Bind handler using jQuery (so remove `onchange="otherTown()"`). Then using jQuery `toggle()` method:

```
$(function() { // shothand for document ready pseudo event, if needed
    $('#town').on('change', function () {
        $("#alt_town").toggle(this.value === "4");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
$('#town').change(function () {
    if($(this).val()==parseInt("4"))
       {
       $('#alt_town').show();
       }else{
            $('#alt_town').hide();
       }
    });
```